# Método Get com where customizavel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Fiz uma `WebAPI` (`ASPNET` com `EF6`) com suporte aos verbos `Get()`, `Post()` e `Delete()`. Em dado momento, preciso acessar determinados valores que não são retornados por padrão pelos verbos, por exemplo:

O Controller de pedidos tem um metodo `Get()` que retornará toda a listagem e um método `Get(int id)` que trará o pedido pelo ID, porém se eu quiser um pedido pelo Id do estabelecimento relacionado eu teria que pegar todos os Pedidos e filtrar na aplicação. Isso me cheira a gambiarra e tornaria a requisição muito pesada.

Gostaria de fazer um `Get()` que receba, por exemplo, um parâmetro `where` e um parâmetro com o valor que eu espero do where, por exemplo `id_estabelecimento/3`. É possível realizar tal feito? existe uma maneira melhor de tratar esse tipo de demanda?

Comment: Linguagem? Framework?

Comment: Perdão, @VirgilioNovic, Adicionei à pergunta

Comment: e se fizer um método para isso! é só fazer outro método e colocar o verbo get também!

Comment: @Csorgo dê uma pesquisada em OData para entity framework. Eu estou sem tempo para criar um exemplo agora, mas acho que vc consegue achar material bom na internet.

Comment: poderia ser um pouco mais claro ? você que um método do seu  controle ou um método get do EF ? que recebe uma query ? poste seu código como tentou fazer mesmo que errado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agradeço muito os comentários dos colegas da comunidade. Conversei com um colega ontem sobre o problema e vi que a melhor forma (por questões de segurança e usabilidade) é criar os endpoints de acordo com o que minha aplicação precisará.
Usei um pouco do padrão `ViewModel` e criei um novo endpoint para retornar apenas o que eu preciso. Segue abaixo com comentários:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("order/estabelecimento/{id}")] //Rota definida a partir do estabelecimento/ para não conflitar com outro endpoint
    public async Task<List<ordemViewModel>> GetByEstablishmentId(string id)
    {
        new OrdemController();
        List <ordemViewModel> orders = await (from itens in db.ordem where itens.id_estabelecimento == id select new ordemViewModel
         //Cria um ViewModel do tipo ordem e solicita apenas os dados que preciso
        { 
          id = itens.id,
          preco = itens.preco
          dataCriacao = itens.dataCriacao
          //Dados que eu preciso
        }).ToListAsync();
        if (!orders.Any())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage error = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Nenhuma ordem encontrada")),
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
                ReasonPhrase = "Order Not Found"
            };
            throw new HttpResponseException(error);
        }
        return orders;
    }
```